# C++ - How can we get a millisecond timestamp in linux?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, unix-timestamp, c++-chrono

How to convert `std::chrono::monotonic_clock::now()` to milliseconds and cast it to long?

using steady_clock or high_resolution_clock from chrono is also same. I have seen into `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>` but I only want the current timestamp and not any duration gaps.

Comment: `clock_gettime()` or `gettimeofday()` both get the current timestamp in a manner that is trivial to convert to milliseconds.  Are you specifically looking to use constructs from `std::chrono`?

Comment: I'm looking towards something that is not subjected to NTP adjustments or any change. I've heard clock_gettime() cannot be fully reliable. gettimeofday is changeable too.

Comment: `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` is the primitive used by `std::chrono::monotonic_clock`.  It is as "not subjected to NTP adjustments or any change" as you can get.

Comment: @Zack: Look at the definitions of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` [here](http://stuff.onse.fi/man?program=clock_gettime&section=3) and you may be surprised.

Comment: So there is a CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, strange. So may be if chrono uses clock_gettime() as the primitive , atleast it uses this raw type may be :)

Comment: @interjay My point is just that `std::chrono` can be no better than the underlying primitive(s) it uses, which in this case is `clock_gettime`.  I confess I don't understand why Linux introduced a distinction between `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` -- "a clock that cannot be set" implies "not subject to NTP adjustments" to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current timestamp is defined with respect to some point in time (hence it is a duration). For instance, it is "typical" to get a timestamp with respect to the beginning of the Epoch (January 1st 1970, in Unix). You can do that by using [`time_since_epoch()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch):

```
namespace chr = std::chrono;

chr::time_point<chr::steady_clock> tp = chr::steady_clock::now();
std::cout << "hours since epoch: "
          << chr::duration_cast<chr::hours>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count()
          << '\n';
```

To get the value in milliseconds you would need to cast it to `std::chrono::milliseconds`, instead.

Comment: I would mark this the answer but I'm going to use the high_resolution_clock because it has the shortest possible tick available.

Comment: @King That should work too. `now()` returns a `time_point` for all the clocks, so you just need to change to clock type.

Comment: yes . just mentioned that it is a better choice for precision.

Comment: The epoch for a clock is not necessarily the Unix epoch of Jan 1st 1970. It may well be something else, such as boot time, or program start time.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams The OP is asking about Unix, so it is actually Jan 1s 1970. I will clarify that in the answer, though.

Comment: Even on Unix, the C++11 clocks do not have a guaranteed epoch. `std::chrono::system_clock` has functions for converting between `time_point` and `time_t`, but may still use any epoch internally, so `tp.time_since_epoch()` will not necessarily give the same result as `to_time_t(tp)`.

Comment: Of course, a specific implementation may document the epoch, but then your code is no longer portable to other platforms or implementations.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams I was just looking at C++ reference and as you said `time_since_epoch` use the epoch internally defined in the clock. I have checked it and in my system is actually Jan 1st 1970, but it may not be like that in another system. Even for `to_time_t` it is stated that epoch is not defined, even if it is almost always Jan 1st 1970.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams Actually I tried to explain the OP that referring to instantaneous points in time (as the OP was suggesting in the question) does not make too much sense. It is always necessary to have some epoch. Today is 2012 just because we are using a particular epoch. So, probably the easiest thing would be for the OP to define an epoch, thus making the application totally portable.

Comment: `to_time_t()` converts to a `time_t`, and which then has the appropriate epoch for `time_t`, which is Jan 1st 1970 on Unix. This may be a POSIX requirement, but I can't remember. I've known non-Unix systems where it is different. I agree that the OP ought to define an epoch --- the easiest way to do this is by getting a `time_point` at the start of the program with *some-clock*`::now()`.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams Exactly. When I have some time I will change the answer to reflect this discussion. Thanks for you feedback!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `cannot convert from 'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point' to 'std::chrono::time_point<_Clock>'`

Comment: @Qix it compiles in gcc (version 4.7; I believe it worked in previous versions too, though). What compiler are you using? It might be the case that your compiler does not fully support C++11 yet.

Comment: MSVC 11 (2012). Anthony Williams' solution compiled fine. I know my compiler supports C++11.

Comment: @Qix As far as I know, no compiler fully supports C++11 at this moment. You can have a look [here](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) and see how MSVC 11 is missing many C++11 features. I guess my code uses some feature that MSVC does not support yet.

Comment: How do I convert this to int64_t?

Answer (score 3):

All the built-in clocks have an associated "epoch" which is their base time. The actual date/time of the epoch is not specified, and may vary from clock to clock.

If you just want a number for comparisons then *some-clock*`::now().time_since_epoch()` will give you a `duration` for the time since the epoch for that clock, which you can convert to an integer with the `count()` member of the `duration` type. The units of this will depend on the `period` of the clock. If you want specific units then use `duration_cast` first:

```
typedef std::chrono::steady_clock clk;
unsigned long long milliseconds_since_epoch=
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        clk::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

As I said, this is only good for comparisons, not as an absolute time stamp, since the epoch is unspecified.

If you need a UNIX timestamp then you need to use `std::chrono::system_clock`, which has a `to_time_t()` function for converting a `time_point` to a `time_t`.

Alternatively, you can take a baseline count at a particular point in your program, along with the corresponding time from `gettimeofday` or something, and then use that to convert relative counts to absolute times.

Comment: time_t is an integer denoting only the seconds. So converting to time_t doesn't help us much when all we need is milliseconds and not just seconds.

Yes. this was an unix specific question. I agree that epoch differs according to the platform you calculate it in. If anyone needs a portable code, then they ought to set epoch.